# Spring RMI， connection refused

Tags: linux, spring, rmi

I'm deploying Spring based RMI server on one machine(10.11.11.11), and the RMI client running on another machine(10.12.11.12), but once client trying to connect RMI server then client throw an "Connection refused" exception, and then I tried to telnet to RMI Server at client side but the response is connected.

Both two machines are Linux system and if running on Windows everything is OK.

Do anybody know what am I missing when using Linux.

Comment: Is it possible that your client is trying to use the service before it's up? Maybe the service is up by the time you telnet to it?

Comment: 'Connection refused' to what host:port?

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one interface in machine, use "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=machine_ip"
note : this is your exporter interface ip

Comment: hi
sorry about late !!!!
use this in java option parameters "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=machine_ip"
machine_ip = server ip (10.11.11.11)
and set in spring rmi exporter "registryHost" property
<property name="registryHost" value="10.11.11.11"/>
good luck